# True/False: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}=0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}=0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$

What I am seeing from this series is that it is the sequence of odd index elements added to the even index elements. This makes me think that it is true because the series are equal but I don't know how I would prove rigorously that this is true.

Comment: $a_1=1, a_2=-1, a_3=1, a_4=-1, \cdots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $a_n = \begin{cases}-1 \text{ if $n$ is odd} \\ 1 \text{ if $n$ is even}\end{cases}$.  Then $a_{2n-1} + a_{2n} = (-1) + 1 = 0$, so that $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty (a_{2n-1} + a_{2n}) = \lim\limits_{N \to +\infty}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^N(a_{2n-1} + a_{2n}) = \lim\limits_{N \to +\infty} 0 = 0$, but the partial sum $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N a_n = (-1) + 1 + (-1) + 1 + \dots = \begin{cases}-1 \text{ if $n$ is odd} \\ 0 \text{ if $n$ is even}\end{cases}$, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ doesn't even exist.

Comment: Why would $a_n$ not exist? Isnt it just $\sum(-1)^n$?

Comment: In the last part, I mean the "infinite sum" doesn't exist, as the partial sums oscillate between $0$ and $-1$.

Comment: So you are saying that the statement is false. I understand what you are getting at now. Thanks the series a_n never converges so the infinite sum cannot be equal to 0